# não consigo criar uma imagem no DOM com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Verificador de Idade</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        Verificador de idade
    </header>
    <section>
        <div>
            <p>Ano de Nascimento: <input type="text" id="anoNascimento"></p>
            <p>sexo: 
                <input type="radio" name="checkSex" id="masculino" checked>Homem 
                <input type="radio" name="checkSex" id="feminino" >Mulher
            <div id="calcular" >Calcular Idade</div>
        </div>
    
        <div id="resultado">preencha os dados a cima para ver o resultado</div>
      
    </section>
    <footer>
        &copy; Curso em video
    </footer>
    
<script src="script.js" >
var calc = document.querySelector('div#calcular');
calc.addEventListener('click', calcular);

function calcular(){

    const data = new Date();
    const ano = data.getFullYear();
    const anoNascimento = document.querySelector('input#anoNascimento');
    var resultado = document.querySelector('div#resultado');
    
    if( anoNascimento.value.length == 0 || anoNascimento.value>ano){
        window.alert('Dados incorretos, tente novamente');
    }else{
        const sex = document.getElementsByName('checkSex');
        const idade = ano - Number(anoNascimento.value);
        var genero = '';
        resultado.innerHTML = `Idade calculada: ${idade}`;
       
        var img = document.createElement(img);
        img.setAttribute('id', 'foto');
        
        if(sex[0].checked){
            genero='homem';
            if(idade>=0 && idade<10){
                img.setAttribute =('src', 'criancaMasculino.jpg');
            }else if(idade<20){
                img.setAttribute=('src','adolescenteMasculino.jpg');
            }else if(idade<50){
                img.setAttribute=('src', 'adulto.jpg');
            }else{
                img.setAttribute=('src', 'idoso.jpg');
            }
        }else if(sex[1]){
            genero='mulher';

            if(idade>=0 && idade<=10){
                img.setAttribute=('src', 'criancaFeminino.jpg');
            }else if(idade<20){
                img.setAttribute=('src', 'adolescenteFeminino.jpg');
            }else if(idade<50){
                img.setAttribute=('src', 'adulta.jpg');
            }else{
                img.setAttribute=('src', 'idosa.jpg');
            }
        }
        resultado.innerHTML=`Detectamos ${genero} com ${idade} anos.`;
       
    }
    resultado.appendChild(img);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ja testei os ifs para ver se o codigo esta acessando as condições e nessa parte não há problema, verifiquei tbm o nome da imagem e a extensão mas mesmo que eu mude a extensão em ambas as partes(no codigo e o proprio arquivo da imagem) mas mesmo assim não consigo exibir o conteúdo.

Comment: `resultado.appendChild('img');` isso está errado, se `img` é uma variável, não deveria vir entre aspas

Comment: eu ja tinha tentado sem as aspas e não estava dando certo, ai fui mexendo no codigo onde eu achava que podia estar errado mas nenhuma das modificações dava certo.

Answer (score 0):

Você declarou `resultado` como uma constante e está tentando modificar.

Verifica também se não será necessário alterar o caminho relativo como por exemplo './nomedaimagem' no src de cada imagem.

Comment: ja verifiquei o nome da imagem e ela está correta.

Comment: as imagens estão no mesmo diretório do html?

Comment: antes elas ficavam em um diretório dentro da pasta do arquivo, mas mudei isso só para ter certeza que o problema não era esse.

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma resposta, mas quero saber de um ponto de vista mais profissional se ela é valida, eu criei o atributo src da foto com o valor " "  antes dos ifs das imagens, e quando a condição é ativada eu só alterei o valor do src.

const calc = document.querySelector('div#calcular');
calc.addEventListener('click', calcular);

function calcular(){
var data =  new Date();
var ano = data.getFullYear();
const anoNascimento = document.querySelector('input#anoNascimento');
var resultado =document.querySelector('div#resultado');

```
if(anoNascimento.value.length==0 || anoNascimento.value > ano){
    window.alert('[ERRO] revise os dados e tente novamente');

}else{
    var sex = document.getElementsByName('checkSex');
    var idade = Number(ano) - Number(anoNascimento.value);
    var genero = '';
   
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('id', 'foto');
    img.setAttribute('src', '');
    if(sex[0].checked){
        genero = 'homem';
        if(idade>=0 && idade<10){
            img.src=('imagem/masculino/crianca.jpeg');
        }else if (idade<19){
            img.src=('imagem/masculino/adolescente.jpeg');
        }else if (idade<50){
            img.src=('imagem/masculino/adulto.jpeg');
        }else{
            img.src=('imagem/masculino/idoso.jpeg');
        }  
    }else if(sex[1].checked){
        genero = 'mulher';
        if(idade>=0 && idade<10){
            img.src=('imagem/feminino/crianca.jpeg');
        }else if (idade<19){
            img.src=('imagem/feminino/adolescente.jpeg');
        }else if (idade<50){
            img.src=('imagem/feminino/adulto.jpeg');
        }else{
            img.src=('imagem/feminino/idoso.jpeg');
        }  
    }
    resultado.innerHTML = `Detectamos ${genero} de ${idade} anos.`;
    resultado.appendChild(img);
}
```

}